# new version of app - new IAPs how to solve?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Now I've got an app in the App Store, with some IAPs. 
I'm making a newer version of this app, but with very new IAPs. I added the new IAPs in iTunes connect, but when I tried to make it for review, it said they will accept it only with a new version of app. So what is the correct sequence? I want to test the new IAPs with my new version.

- make the new version, upload
- wait until they accept, but I don't let them publish?
- then send for review the new IAPs?
- after can test the new IAPs?

Can somebody tell me the correct sequence?

Answer (score 0):

To add new IAPs and control the release of them, you

1. make new IAPs
2. create a new version of your app that includes the IAPs and set to developer release.
3. upload the new version

To test your IAPs, you only need to create them in iTunes Connect. You can then create test iTunes users and test your purchases in developer and ad hoc builds of your app. Make sure to log out of iTunes & App Store in the Settings.app and to log in using an Existing Apple ID in your app.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't test them until they don't accept it. Now I'm added all of my new IAPs, but when I'm running my app, and listing the available IAPs, only the olds are in. So I think I can only test it after apple accepted my new version, and I set it to developer release.

Comment: No, you can test before review: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Comment: I can be blind, but I can't find anything about testing before review, if I have an 'old' version with 'old' IAPs in the store. Please can u help me?

Comment: If you run a developer build from Xcode, you should be able to start a SKProductsRequest with product identifiers that have not yet been reviewed.

Comment: Be sure to delete the old 'production' version of your App from your device before reinstalling a new version of your App from Xcode otherwise your App will go to the production environment and not the sandbox environment.  Your new IAPs will only be in the sandbox environment.